# How do I obtain the correct value in the W-register after a MOVF operation

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, debugging

How do I obtain the correct value in the W-register after a MOVF operation?

I am debugging a code which builds & programs successfully, but does not have the desired result when powered up as part of the circuit and I have noticed that the working register does not contain the right value after a MOVF operation, whilst debugging.

If the value that is being copied to the W-reg is manually written in during debugging, then the code functions as it should.

The following images, I believe, illustrate the my issue quite well.

[image]

**1. Port definition.**

[image]

**2. LEDportA value of 0x02 is to be moved to the W-reg.**

[image]

**3. After the operation, W-reg contains 0x00, instead of 0x02.**

[image]

**4. Final image shows that LEDportA is the same as LATA, as it is cleared after the "clrf LEDportA instruction.**

I am totally bewildered as to what could be causing it and any insights or advice that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.

Please note that the PIC MCU in use is the PIC16F1829.

Comment: Which PIC? (So potential responders can grab the relevant datasheet, or better yet, add a link in the question yourself). Is `LEDportA` an alias for `LATA` ? If so why not call it `LEDlatA` ? Can we see the definition of `LEDportA` ?

Comment: If LEDportA is actually PORTA and not LATA, I may have a possible explanation.

Comment: @Tagli Yes, that's why I asked. Reads from `PORTA` read the actual port, writes go to `LATA`.

Comment: Please accept my apologise for not stating the PIC model and posting the entire code. Not quite sure why I thought doing that to be irrelevant. Pls note LEDportA is actually LATA as outlined by the "clrf LEDportA" instruction setting LATA to 0x00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set portA to digital I/O. Usually it defaults to analogue inputs at powerup?

If left in analogue mode it will function as a digital output but when read will return 0x00.

Read the A to D converter section of the data sheet and find the register which needs to be written to change portA from analogue mode to digital mode.

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this as a "question posted as an answer". Consider using imperative in answers, i.e. "Set port A to digital IO..."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You are correct that I had not set portA to digital I/O using the ANSEL register. However, that is not what is causing my issue. My problem was that my TempC register is located 0x70 in bank 0, and the LATA register is located at 0x10C bank 2 in memory. Thus when I attempted to read from LATA, I was actually reading the corresponding 0C addres location in bank0. Therefore, I have to switch to the correct bank, bank 1 in this case, before I can attempt to copy the value from the LATA register.

Comment: @aLoHa , that was the fist thing came to my mind. But if you are on the wrong bank, how can `clrf LEDportA` affect `LATA` register?

Comment: @Tagli Writing to portA or LATA both write to the data latch. LATA is the direct outputs of the data latch where as portA is the buffered version of the data latch. Therefore portA is just a buffered version of LATA. However either can be read independently.

Comment: @aLoHa That's good. You will be able to read LATA correctly independent of whether the I/O is set to analogue or digital, but if you want to read portA (the actual pins) you must have the port configured as digital I/O even if the port is set as outputs (TRISA = 0x00) and despite the fact that, with the port set as outputs, LATA will have the same value as portA.

Comment: ..... apart from perhaps for a very short period of time after a write.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which I was able to resolve my problem was to select the correct bank for LATA, before attempting to read from it.